# Axis labels are not visible of an chart in ExtJS 4

Tags: charts, extjs4, ria, rich-internet-application

I am trying to draw an chart inside panel. Chart bars are getting drawn correctly but x and y axis labels are not shown when chart is drawn. Code to draw chart is as follows :

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.form.*',
    'Ext.chart.*',
    'Ext.layout.container.*'
]);

Ext.define('ilp.view.EmployeeCountControl', {
    extend : 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.employeeCountControl',

    require : [
        'ilp.store.Employees',
        'ilp.store.Dimensions'
    ],

    layout : {
        type : 'vbox',
        align : 'stretch',
        pack : 'start'
    },

    title : 'Select dimension to view chart',

    initComponent : function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype : 'combobox',
                fieldLabel : 'Select Dimension',
                store : 'Dimensions',
                queryMode : 'local',
                displayField : 'name',
                valueField : 'dimension',
                flex : 1
            },
            {
                xtype : 'chart',
                title : 'selected dimension',
                store : 'Employees',
                flex : 2,
                width: 150,
                height: 200,
                legend : {
                    position : 'right'
                },
                axes : [
                    {
                        title : 'Emp Count',
                        type : 'Numeric',
                        position : 'left',
                        fields : ['hpCount', 'nonhpCount'],
                        minimum : 0,
                        grid : true
                    },
                    {
                        title : 'selected dimension',
                        type : 'Category',
                        position : 'bottom',
                        fields : ['dimension']
                    }
                ],
                series : [
                    {
                        type : 'bar',
                        column :true,
                        stacked : true,
                        highlight: true,
                        axis : 'left',
                        xField : ['dimension'],
                        yField : ['hpCount', 'nonhpCount'],
                        yPadding : 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and what gets drawn is as follows :

[image]

As you can see, title and axis values are not being displayed on chart.

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening??

Thanks in advance !!

---

**EDIT 1**

After moving `legend` to bottom, I got x axis values but now those values are getting hidden behind legend and also those values are going out of panel. Does anyone knows how to decrease the size of actual chart and bars to fit axis values properly? My chart now looks as follows :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set **Width** and/or **Padding** to your Layout and/or Panel and see the changes. I think it's about the chart parent container not the chart itself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will certainly try setting width/padding attributes. and what will be potential problem with chart parent container? I have tried to set 'layout' to fit, anchor, vbox but output remains same. I found out that there is some bug with ExtJS 4.0.3 so I downloaded new version 4.1RC3 but problem still exists.

Comment: What about this example? http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/charts/Column2.html Do you have any problem with this?

Comment: my problem is solved now. I had to change the 'autoLoad' property of store to 'true' to load the chart data as soon as panel is displayed. I am not using stacked chart now. It seems there is some problem with ExtJS stacked bar chart.